# Maximum Likelihood Estimation-MLE

Tags: machine-learning

I have this question related to "Maximum Likelihood Estimation"...I've tried to solve it but I couldn't ... would you please help!

Suppose for an event X, there are three possible 
values, A, B and C. Now we repeat X for N times. The number of times that we observe A or B 
is N1, the number of times that we observe A or C is N2. Let pA be the unknown frequency of 
value A. Please give the maximum likelihood estimation of pA

Comment: N1+N2-N (easy to see using Venn diagram)

Comment: would you please explain more?

Comment: this sounds like homework

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [maths.se]

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't really belong in Stackoverflow, but I will answer it anyway.

You can look at the number of observations of A (I am calling this N_A) as a hidden variable and maximize with respect to the marginal distribution (the sum over all possible values of N_A).

There is no closed form solution, in general, for the MLE parameters - solutions are the zeros of a polynomial constrained to the simplex. Below, I have derived an Expectation Maximization updates.

[image]
[image]